# Getting rid of a GPT signature without touching MBR

Tags: unix, partitioning, mbr, gpt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GParted errors on MBR Disk, Claims it's GPT. (It's mistaken, but why?)](https://superuser.com/questions/293339/gparted-errors-on-mbr-disk-claims-its-gpt-its-mistaken-but-why)

I have a disk that seems to contain both an MBR and a GPT. When trying to access the partition table with GNU fdisk, it tells me:

```
# fdisk /dev/sdh
GNU Fdisk 1.2.4

Warning: /dev/sdh contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake
msdos partition table, as it should.  Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT
partition table?
   y   Yes                                                                
   n   No
```

If I answer "No" the program just exits. If I answer yes, I get to continue, but only get an empty disk:

```
y
Using /dev/sdh
Command (m for help): p                                                   

Disk /dev/sdh: 500 GB, 500105249280 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System 
Command (m for help):
```

parted and GNU cfdisk behave the same way. When using the standard Linux fdisk, I get

```
# fdisk.distrib /dev/sdh

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdh'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdh: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc645f603

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdh1              63   976768064   488384001   83  Linux

Command (m for help):
```

so this time the partition seems to be there. The Linux kernel seems to behave the same way, because I can access the partition just fine.

My question: how can I get rid of the GPT signature, so that GNU fdisk stops refusing to use the MBR, and Linux fdisk stops giving the warning?

Comment: Question http://superuser.com/questions/293339/gparted-errors-on-mbr-disk-claims-its-gpt-its-mistaken-but-why lead me to http://rodsbooks.com./gdisk/wipegpt.html, which describes how to use the gdisk program to do what I need: zap the GPT while keeping the MBR untouched. Can't answer the question myself because of the timeout.